# iOS distribution via manifest.plist - using query string parameters in url string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, manifest, distribution

My company rolls our own distribution platform for iOS apps. Currently our system works well using the following method:

```
<dict>
    <key>kind</key>
    <string>software-package</string>
    <key>url</key>
    <string>http://mydomain.com/app.ipa</string>
</dict>
```

We're hosting our IPAs on Amazon S3 with no layer of security. Problem is that i'm wanting to add a secure layer, which will involve passing a query string along with the IPA string to enable the download, like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>kind</key>
    <string>software-package</string>
    <key>url</key>
    <string>http://mydomain.com/app.ipa?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxx</string>
</dict>
```

As soon as we add parameters to the url string however, the install will no longer work (the error is "Cannot connect to mydomain.com").

Trying the link directly (with query string) works fine, so it's not an issue with the URL.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to fix this / work arounds?

Cheers,
Jason

**EDIT:** Fixed in comment below.

Comment: If I recall correctly, iOS blocks all calls to any URL's that are not explicitly allowed in your manifest file.. Did you allow your domain?

Comment: Hey, see my edit above... i've fixed the issue by encoding the URL string (can't post as an answer cause i'm still a n00b).

Comment: If you wait a while you should be able to post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Derp. I seem to have resolved this myself. Encoding the url string (using htmlspecialchars in php) has fixed the issue (characters such as & need to be encoded as &amp;).

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jason, do you need to escape everything in this [list](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php) ? What about "%" character. Is there a js function that does this easily. Thanks.